# Decline all URIs with tilde character in Nginx

Tags: regex, webserver, nginx

I would like to return a 403 whenever a request contains a tilde character (~)

Example: `https://example.com/~/item-1/` or even. `https://example.com/item1?status=~pending`

I want the above to return a 403

My idea is to have something like the config below, but I'm not sure how to complete the regex part.

```
map $request_uri $filefromarg {
    [WHAT-REGEX-HERE];
    default $request_uri;
}

try_files $filefromarg $uri =403;
```

Kindly share how to do this and the possible regex pattern.

Comment: Asking for best is asking for opinions,  which is off topic, so I  have edited it. You can edit it further to make it more to your liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This config is based on post
[How to block access to php tilde files in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739187/how-to-block-access-to-php-tilde-files-in-nginx):

```
server 
{
   listen          80 default_server;

   index           index.html;
   root            /var/www/default;

   [... other stuff ...]

   location ~ ~ 
   {
      return 403;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works well i.e as expected